# MySQL Error Code: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mysql query to select  at least two  or more than same user subscription.Here's the query:

```
  SELECT a.* FROM `subscription` a, user b WHERE b.id=a.user_id and 
        count(a.user_id) > 1 group by a.id
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: aggregate function are not allowed in where clause

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `having` with Aggregate functions.
`Where` is used to filter rows. `Having` is used to filter groups based on given condition.

```
SELECT a.* FROM `subscription` a, user b WHERE b.id=a.user_id 
 group by a.id
having count(a.user_id) > 1
```

Also, use ANSI Syntax for `Join` as follows:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM `subscription` a 
inner join 
user b 
on b.id=a.user_id 
group by a.id
having count(a.user_id) > 1
;
```